# Prove that the power series is convergent for $|x| < r$

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing, power-series

Here is the problem:

Let $\{a_n\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ be a series. We assume there is a $r > 0$ so that the series $\{a_nr^n \}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ is limited(?). Show that the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_xx^n$$
Is absolute convergent when $|x| < r$.

As far as I know, that the series is limited means that there is a lower and upper bound for it. Does that imply that $a_n$ is limited when $|r| < 1$?

And $r = x$ sort of?

Comment: "bounded" instead of "limited", is the word you are looking for, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean "bounded" rather than limited. Assume that there exists $M>0$ such that
$$|a_nr^n|\leq M$$
for every $n\geq 0$. If $|x|<r$ we have
$$|a_nx^n|=|a_nr^n|\left|\dfrac{x}{r}\right|^n\leq M\left(\dfrac{|x|}{r}\right)^n$$
Now $0\leq|x|/r<1$ so that the geometric series
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\dfrac{|x|}{r}\right)^n$$
is convergent. This shows that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n}$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I'm pretty slow, but you multiply both sides with$$|\frac{x}{r}|^n$$ How did you figure that out?

Comment: No I'm just writing $x^n=\dfrac{r^nx^n}{r^n}$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

There is $C>0$ such that $|a_nr^n|\leq C$, hence $|a_n| \le \frac{C}{r^n}$, therefore

$\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n} \le \frac{1}{r}$. Cauchy and Hadamard say: the radius of convergence is $ \ge r$